# If $f’$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to prove ‘If $f,f’$ is differentiable on open interval on $R$ and $f’’$ is bounded by $M$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on the same interval’.

It is suffices to show $f’$ is bounded.

So I wanna check $f’’$ is bounded and $f’$ is differentiable(implies continuous) on open interval implies $f’$ is bounded

Thank you

Comment: The question in the title isn't the same as the one you're asking in the post itself. If the interval is allowed to be unbounded (e.g. all of $\mathbb R$), then a simple counterexample (to the question in the post) is $f(x) = x^2$, so $f'(x) = 2x$ and $f''(x) = 2$.

Comment: @Bungo: It kinda does, right? Eventually, OP is asking whether boundedness of $g'$ implies boundedness of $g$. The title is for $g  = f$ and the post is for $g = f'$.

Comment: I assume your original question is about open, bounded intervals?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani True, but it's a bit weird that the title assumes only continuity of $f$ yet also refers to $f'$. Would be good if the OP would clarify, as the title is the first thing most people will see.

Comment: (Also, any answer needs to indicate which $f$ it's talking about, the one in the title or the one in the question...)

Comment: It looks to me as if the OP has passed up the opportunity to tie up these loose ends (the open interval is bounded, title is different problem than the body, etc.), so I'm voting to close (put on hold pending fixes).

Answer (score 2):

The question in the title is not the same as the one in the question body, although they're equivalent. I'll address the one in the title:

> If $f'$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous (and presumably differentiable since $f'$ is defined!), then is $f$ bounded?

If the interval can be unbounded, then $f$ need not be bounded: for example, if the interval is $\mathbb R$, then a counterexample is $f(x) = x$.

If the interval is bounded, say $(a,b)$, then the result is true: $f$ is bounded. Pick a fixed point $c \in (a,b)$. Then for any other point $x \in (a,b)$, $x \neq c$, the mean value theorem tells us that there is some $d$ between $c$ and $x$ such that

$$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = f'(d)$$

and therefore

$$\frac{|f(x) - f(c)|}{b-a} \leq \frac{|f(x) - f(c)|}{|x-c|} = |f'(d)|$$

Assuming $|f'|$ is bounded by $M$, this implies that

$$|f(x) - f(c)| \leq M(b-a)$$

and so

$$|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(c) + f(c)| \leq |f(x) - f(c)| + |f(c)| \leq M(b-a) + |f(c)|$$

so $f$ is bounded.